# Python - How to iterate through a list inside a dataframe column skiping the nan

Tags: list, dataframe, nan

I need to iterate through a list inside a dataframe’s column. The problem is that sometimes I have missing values that make me get the error: “float' object is not iterable”.
I don’t want to replace de missing values, so I need to skip it. I have a hug dataframe, but I show you just a little example:

```
dic = {"E1x":[19.2, 20.7,5.2, 6.5,-2],"E2x": [-9,3,2.5,-4,5],"E1y":[-1,2,5,7,8], "E2y":[3,5,17,-20,15], "Ata":[[23,10], [5,7,3], [20,23], np.nan, [2,5]]}
df=pd.DataFrame(dic)

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Ata'] is not None:
        for e in row["Ata"]:
            print(e)
```

How can I do to iterate through the column “Ata” skiping the NaN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use boolean-indexing:

```py
mask = df["Ata"].notna()

for i, row in df[mask].iterrows():
    for e in row["Ata"]:
        print(e)
```

Prints:

```
23
10
5
7
3
20
23
2
5
```

---

EDIT: To check if the value is `list`:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if isinstance(row["Ata"], list):
        for e in row["Ata"]:
            print(e)
```

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't fix my problem because I need to iterate all over the dataframe and not only in df[mask].

Comment: Now it's ok. Thank you so much!